# How to solve System.Net.Sockets.SocketException on C# Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mailkit, mimekit

In my app I want to send an email, it works fine in debugging mode but when I release it I get this error. I'm already catching the exception but that causes it to not send the email and I really need this function to work. How is this caused and how can it be solved that it also works when deployed? I've tested it on multiple phones and they all gave this exception so the phone used is not the issue.

Corresponding code:

```
 this.Dismiss();
var message = new MimeMessage();
message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Name", "Email"));
message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Name", "Email"));
message.Subject = "Test"

message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
{
    Text = @"Test"
};

using (var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
{
    try
    {
        client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
        client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 25, false);

        // Note: since we don't have an OAuth2 token, disable
        // the XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.

        client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
        client.Authenticate("Account", "Password");

        client.Send(message);
        client.Disconnect(true);

        Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "Thanks for the email", Android.Widget.ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
    catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException e)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "Connection error, please try again later!", Android.Widget.ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
```

At "Name" and "Email" is the corresponding information but changed it for this example. Same as "Account" and "Password" in client.Authenticate for security.

EDIT: Error code is 11001, and message was could not resolve host "smtp.gmail.com" , this also happens on the other ports. The thing I find weird is that it works when debugging on my emulator, but not on the phones when it's deployed.

Comment: Use SSL, port 587. I'm guessing that's the issue you're having with Google.

Comment: Does the address you using the app FROM matters? as in, your dev is ip A and release is ip B? Then take a look at the instructions from google. I believe you need a stronger password.

Comment: Exceptions have a `Message` property, and `SocketException` has an `ErrorCode` property - can you include those in your question?

Comment: You have to check Gmail documentation on which parameters to use. Like other comments said, you don't even get the correct port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dumb mistake, I forgot to add permissions to acces internet.

Bit weird though that it does work in debugging mode then.

Comment: Good catch, Ewan! :)

Comment: @Ewan Klomp Can you update this response and tell us exactly what permissions you had to change or how to change them?

Comment: @ProfessorTom It has been a long time since I looked at this code but you can check out how to change permissions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=windows I guess it is the INTERNET permission though.